# Mouse freezes after ~10 minutes

Tags: drivers, mouse

On my other computer which is Win XP, after about 10 minutes -- sometimes longer, sometimes much shorter -- the mouse freezes. I can still move the cursor using the numerical keypad to navigate. There are no relevant entries in the error log. No indications of anything amiss in the Device Manager. It could be overheating but I don't think so as the fan operates like it always has?

No virus, 100 percent certain of that. Fully patched, fully up to date.

About the only thing that could be a clue is that the mouse will often freeze during heavy hard-disk activity. CPU activity has nothing to do with it, it happens even with CPU utilized as little as ten percent.

What should I investigate next? Could ít be a problem with the driver, even if nothing shows in Device Manager?

Comment: Did you try another mouse ? what mouse is it ?

Comment: @Ofiris Well duh! It hadn't occurred to me to try that... Please convert your comment to an Answer so that I may accept it.

Comment: Sure, posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sometimes longer, sometimes much shorter -- the mouse freezes`

`No virus, 100 percent certain of that. Fully patched, fully up to date.`

If everything is ok, its the mouse which is bad, try another one.